# Can a view be created by a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create procedure pro_training2
as 
begin
    create view Tab1view As
      select * from tab1
end
```

Is this possible to create a view in the procure?

Comment: Why, oh why, would you want to do this? And can you decide whether you're using MySQL or SQL Server please?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pro_training2
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'CREATE VIEW dbo.Tab1View AS SELECT <columns> FROM dbo.tab1;';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

But this is a serious code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged with MySQL though the above is not MySQL syntax.

Anyway, if you did mean for MySQL: yes, it is possible to issue `CREATE VIEW` from within a procedure, but using a different syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_training2()
MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN
  create view Tab1view As select * from tab1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sp_executesql and specify the Database name:

```
EXEC myDb1..sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW Tab1view As select * from tab1'
```